# aiohttp's analogue of flask_restful request parser

Tags: flask, flask-restful, aiohttp

Flask-RESTful has pretty solid and convinient request parser functional which guarantees arguments to be found in specific locations (like body, args, query), be (or not) required, be of specific type only
If no arguments are found, they are `None` in data

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('argument', type=int, required = True, location='args')
data = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm interesting if there is similar library that I can use with `aiohttp`, or if there is no such and I'm to write my own, maybe there is any advices on what should I pay attention?

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is 
https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-apispec/

By the way, I noticed that `RequestParser` is going to be deprecated in near future, so don't write new apps with it in Flask_RESTful if you do